# Home network setup is 100mbps or 1gbps depending on topology

Tags: networking, gigabit-ethernet

I'll start with the topology, since changes to it will make the problem apparent:
[image: desired setup]

This is the setup as it is supposed to be. I noticed recently at desktop_NBD that the speed seems to be limited to 100mbps, so i went and looked at the netgear switch: no1 and no5 were green, no10 and no11 were yellow. According t

### Specific description of topology

All devices support gigabit ethernet, desktop_NBD 2.5gb even. All cables are cat5e or better. I can add the full name of all cables if needed. The cables in the walls (so wallsocket to netgear switch) are all wired as T568A by the previous owner of the house.

desktop_NBD, desktop_TS, desktop_AD and switch_tplink are upstairs in a room together, which contains wallsocket_10 and 11. raspberry_pi is on the ground floor, with wallsocket_5. router_fritzbox_7590 is in another room on the groundfloor, with wallsocket_1.

The switch_ngetgear_jgs524f is in the basement, were all wallsocket cables terminate into a punchdown panel (this does *not* seem to be a proper gigabit punchdown panel, but since you can see with the test cases, this does not seem to matter) and then into the switch via several short ethernet cables; the numbering scheme down here is identical with the wallsockets.

Both switches support MDI-X.

### Question

What is wrong with my setup that i don't have gigabit speed on all devices? See the below tests because i'm out of ideas - any suggestions appreciated!

### Tests i have done

I performed all bandwith tests with iperf2 and iperf3 (the fritzbox only has iperf2).

I forced 1gbit full duplex in the driver settings for the used network adapters of desktop_AD, desktop_NBD and desktop_TS. Although initially these were on auto ofcourse.

With the desired setup, i get the following numbers:

| client | server | speed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| desktop_AD | desktop_NBD | 95mbit/s |
| desktop_AD | fritzbox | 94mbit/s |
| desktop_AD | raspberry_pi | 95mbit/s |
| desktop_NBD | fritzbox | 90mbit/s |
| desktop_NBD | raspberry_pi | 95mbit/s |
| desktop_TS | desktop_NBD | 380mbit/s |
| desktop_TS | fritzbox | 83mbit/s |
| raspberry_pi | fritzbox | 500mbit/s |

Obviously my first thought was that the cables in the wall for no10 and no11 were simply broken, since i can easily reach above 100mbit/s from desktop_TS to desktop_NBD (desktop_TS network goes through its docking station, i assume thats why its slowish).

I have a simple cable tester ([like this](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/deleyCON-Network-cable-tester-network/dp/B09MQQR5LQ/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=Ethernet%20Kabeltester%20Rj45&qid=1660477884&sr=8-3)) and have tested all cables involved. all 8 lights light up for every cable. I tested the cables in the wall by putting in another cable on each end, i guess that is fine?

So it shouldn't be cables. Then i plugged into wallsocket_10 directly with desktop_NBD, to circumvent the switch. That gives me 900mbit/s between raspberry_pi and desktop_NBD! And as somewhat expected, speed between desktop_NBD and fritzbox is now also at 350mbit/s. I used the cable which was inside switch_tplink before.

Alright, lets plug that same cable into desktop_AD (still using wallsocket_10, as before with the switch and desktop_NBD) and see what happens. Still 95mbit/s to the raspberry pi.

So i repeated that test with desktop_TS. Again only 95mbit/s.

Another weird thing: When i first went into the basement, no1 and no5 were green, no10 and no11 were yellow. Since i wanted to take a look at the wiring of the patchpanel, i turned off the power for the switch and unmounted the patchpanel. Cabling looked okay, so i didnt do anything, screwed it back in and turned on the power. Since i did that, when plugging in no1 will blink green for about 10seconds and then turn yellow. But it seems that it has no impact on the speed between raspberry_pi and fritzbox, i repeated that test again.

Comment: The picture is unique to your setup. Try placing the main device (Frtiz box?) at the head by itself and then add devices slowly until you determine which device is slow. Process of trial and elimination.

Comment: just because a 'simple' test is good dosen't mean that a cable's 'correct' - it might be worth getting a professional to check it and/or redo those runs

Comment: @JourneymanGeek we have an electrician coming over to put in cables for the attic, i will ask him for that, thanks. I still cannot wrap my head around why plugging in desktop_NBD directly gives me above 100mbit but not for desktop_AD and desktop_TS.

Comment: Do you have another switch to test with that's not a TL-SG10x?

Comment: @user1686 Unfortunately not right now, but i can get one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more testing i found out that it's very likely a combination of three issues: A quality issue with the punch down panel, slightly badly punched cable on that panel and the netgear switch having some faulty ports.

Especially helpful figuring this out was going around with the tplink switch and a laptop and connecting them to all the other wallsockets i had, as well as directly connecting it with a short cable to the netgear switch (so laptop->switch_tplink->switch_netgear). This gave above 100mbit/s. And also gave that for *some* of the wallsockets.

What i finally did was restore my original setup, but repunch the cable on the punch down panel into a completely different slot (and properly) and then trying out different slots on the switch_netgear. Where i found that slot 22,23,24 work and the other are at 100mbit/s.

An observation i made: That blinking in green and then going orange after 5-10sec is probably some kind of negotiation/speed finding. And it never results in a gigabit connection.